# Magento - Produto Configurável

Tags: magento

Fala galera!

Então, é o seguinte, estou com problemas ao adicionar um produto configurável no magento. Estou usando a versão 1.9.2.1.

Acontece o seguinte, eu consigo criar e configurar tudo de boa, porém quando eu seleciono as opções e clico em comprar, a página me retorna o seguinte erro:

**> Please specify the product's option(s).**

Alguém já teve o mesmo problema?
Preciso de uma ajudinha, por favor!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parece que você não adicionou os produtos associados.
Clique na aba produtos associados localizado à esqueda. Veja se possui produtos, se eles estão em estoque e se estão associados ao mesmo site que o produto configurável.